# Change colors with ImageDataGenerator

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm using keras ImageDataGenerator for preprocessing training images and need some kind of color change function (random color, hue change).

My code for generator looks like this:

```
image_generator = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(                                 
                              horizontal_flip = True,
                              brightness_range= [0.7, 1.3],
                              rotation_range = 10,
                              zoom_range = [0.8, 1.2],
                              width_shift_range=0.2,
                              height_shift_range=0.2,
                             fill_mode="nearest")
```

I tried to go throught keras manual for datagerator and the best i found was - channel_shift_range but it works more like brightness/contrast.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [this](https://medium.com/@halmubarak/changing-color-space-hsv-lab-while-reading-from-directory-in-keras-c8ca243e2d57) can help. You can define a customize function to use it in the ImageDataGenerator in order to modify the image colors.

For example:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

def myFunc(image):
    image = np.array(image)
    hsv_image = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_RGB2HSV)
    return Image.fromarray(hsv_image)

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
                rescale=1. / 255,
                rotation_range=20,
                width_shift_range=0.2,
                height_shift_range=0.2,
                horizontal_flip=True,
                preprocessing_function = myFunc
                )
```

Answer (score 0):

Found something while reading an article on Medium. It might be of help :-

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
def myFunc(image):
    image = np.array(image)
    hsv_image = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_RGB2HSV)
    return Image.fromarray(hsv_image)

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1. / 255,
    rotation_range=20,
    width_shift_range=0.2,
    height_shift_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True,
    preprocessing_function = myFunc
    )
```

Source :-

*https://medium.com/@halmubarak/changing-color-space-hsv-lab-while-reading-from-directory-in-keras-c8ca243e2d57*

Comment: Please quote the relevant parts of the article in your answer (in case the link becomes invalid, or the article is deleted, etc).